# Shell script is a directory issue

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
echo $dir #prints chia-blockchain/
echo $dir | sed -e s,-blockchain/,, # prints chia
forkname = `$dir | sed -e s,-blockchain/,,`# not working
```

For some reason last line gives me  this error :
./newfork.sh: line 15: chia-blockchain/: Is a directory
./newfork.sh: line 15: forkname: command not found

Comment: Get rid of the spaces in `forkname = $(dir ...)` (and use the more robust `$( ... )` notation instead of backticks

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: You don't need `sed`, either. `forkname=${dir%-blockchain}` will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, doing `forkname = ...` make the shell believe you are trying to execute a command called `forkname`. It should be `forkname=...`. You second problem is that you have `$dir | sed...`, you have missed out the echo, `echo $dir | sed...`, in that it is trying to execute whatever is in `$dir`.